# Python for loop does not start anymore at 0

Tags: python, pygame

The method mover works fine till the elements of the list are organized in a different order than before. At this time in the method mover, the z variable gets 4 and then the for loop (line 39) counts form 1 to 4 instead from 0 to 3. Any Idea how i am able to fix this?
I would be really happy if someone is able to solve this question.

```
import sys
import pygame
import random

screenx = 500
screeny = 800

go = True
speed = 0

playerx = 40
playery = 540

#zuerst xanfang dann xende
gap = [200,300,300,400,100,200]

coordx = [0,300,0,400,0,200]
coordy = [-250,-250,-250,-250,-250,-250]
length = [120,120,120,120,120,120]
width = [200,200,300,100,100,300]

loops = 2
z = 2

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screenx,screeny])
screen.fill((0,0,0))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
imgmid = pygame.image.load("figurschwarz.png")

def drawer():
    for i in range(len(coordx)):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (230,10,60), (coordx[i],coordy[i],width[i],length[i]), 0)

def mover():
    global z,coordy
    if loops % 250 == 0 and z<len(coordx)-1:
        z = z+2
    for x in range(0,z):
        print (x)
        if coordy[x] <= screeny+10:
            coordy[x] += 2  
        else:
            z -= 2
            print ("pop")
            for s in range(2):
                for f in range(z):
                    print(f)
                    coordy[f] = coordy[f+1]
                print (coordy)
            coordy.pop(z+1)
            coordy.pop(z)
            print (coordy)



def collisiondetection():
    global go
    #player on the left or right wall
    if playerx <= 0 or playerx+40 >= screenx:
        go = False


while go == True:
    loops += 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                speed = -2
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed = 2
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    playerx += speed
    screen.blit(imgmid, (playerx,playery))
    mover()
    drawer()
    collisiondetection()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(110)

print ("Dein Score ist " + str(loops))
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little bit what `mover()` is doing in the game? I am looking at the code, but I would like to know what this `mover()` function is doing.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, mover() is basically moving obstacles from the top to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put one more `print` before the `for` loop of `x`

```
def mover():
global z,coordy
if loops % 250 == 0 and z<len(coordx)-1:
    print("loops = ".format(loops))
    z = z+2
print("range(0,z) = {}".format(range(0,z))) #<----Put this for debugging
for x in range(0,z):
    print ("x = {}".format(x))
    if coordy[x] <= screeny+10:  #<---------- Problem is here
        coordy[x] += 2  
    else:
        ...do something...
```

You will get the following output just before the index error:

[image]

You can see that the loop is actually counting from 0, but the `if` condition is not satisfied, therefore it prints the `'pop'` inside the `else` condition. After that it prints another x. Since the previous value was 0, this time it prints 1. And you thought the `x` starts with 1 here, which is not true.

The real cause of the index error is after popping out the final 2 values from the `coordy` list, the length of the `coordy` list is only 4. However, the range of x is from 0 to 5. So when x=4, your `coordy[4]` is trying to get the 5th element from the list which is non-existent. That's why you get your index error.